# In Android Studio I want a QR code to return an Image on screen when the QR Code is scanned

Tags: android, android-studio

I have developed an app where a QR Code Scanner returns two pieces of text that the QR Code holds. I am new to coding using android studio and for the most part have used tutorials to get this far. I am now looking to return an Image on screen, that a QR Code holds when it is scanned. Is this possible?

Below is the code that returns the text to the app from the QR Code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        //if qrcode has nothing in it
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //if qr contains data
            try {
                //converting the data to json
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.getContents());
                //setting values to textviews
                textViewName.setText(obj.getString("name"));
                textViewAddress.setText(obj.getString("address"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //if control comes here
                //that means the encoded format not matches
                //in this case you can display whatever data is available on the qrcode
                //to a toast
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a QR code with the URL to fetch the image and show it. QR codes can store a very small amount of data to hold an image.

**EDIT:**

To show the actual image instead of its URL, you just need to add an `ImageView` to your layout (you can remove the `TextView`s if you want) and load the image on it after reading the QR code. In order to do that the simplest way possible, you can use the Picasso library. [This post](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android) explains very well how to install it and use it.
Give it a try and let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: Is it possible to get the app to automatically open the url as opposed to just showing the url on screen as is happening now?

Comment: It's surely possible. Can you share some of your code?

Comment: I have added some code to the original post. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if you need some more help.